# Webpack externals doesn't seem to work for nested objects.

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-3

I was using my webpack externals like this and it works fine.

```
externals: {
    react: {
       root: React
    }
  }
```

But now I am injecting the webpack script for a child window , so instead of Window , React is now available in window.parent. So basically any calls to import React should fallback to window.parent.React

How do i do this using externals ? I have tried like this

```
externals: {
    react: {
       root: ["parent", "React"]
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't work. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer to this

```
externals: {
  react: "parent.React"
}
```

is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

You should specify how it will be on the global, try that:

```
externals: {
  react: {
    root: "window.parent.React"
  }
}
```

Comment: I did try this , but didnt work. I searched for the string "window.parent.React" in the bundle that webpack made and only place it appears is a comment like // EXTERNAL MODULE: external {"root":"window.opener.React"}
var external___root___window_opener_React__ = __webpack_require__("275976081ce1abf67779");
var external___root___window_opener_React___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(external___root___window_opener_React__);